# How to get VS Code's Intellisense to work with AngularJS's injected services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So I'm trying to get Visual Studio Code to provide me with its intellisense for my **AngularJs** (not Angular) app's services. I managed to get the standard type for angular (now when I type "angular." it suggests stuff like module, etc). That works and it's great, however I can't find a way to get it to work with my services (or factories). I know, it's not that easy for an IDE to figure the code that comes through dependency injection, etc.

BUT it seems to work fine when both my controller and the service it's using are in the same JS file! The only issue I have with this is that my app is way too large to be all on one JS file and as soon as I split the code in more than one file, it fails.

Note that I have tried using the "triple-slash directive" (///  ) and that did not help.
I've been banging my head on this for the whole day, would really appreciate any help.

Code sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', 'test',
    function ($scope, test) {

        $scope.test = test.word; //TRY TYPING 'test.' --> want to have intellisense suggest 'word'

}]);
//PUT THE BELOW IN ANOTHER FILE AND INTELLISENSE DOES NOT SHOW 'word'
app.service('test', [function(){
    /**
     * @type {string}
     */
    this.word = "balls";
    /**
     * @function
     * @param {string} variable
     */
    this.getLower = function (variable) {
        return variable.toLowerCase();
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <p class="lead">{{test}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention trying to use triple-slash directives, but it's unclear (from your snippet at least) whether you're actually using TypeScript. If you aren't using the latter, you'll need to if you want improved IntelliSense across your files.

VS Code is providing you the limited IntelliSense you're seeing from the [type definitions provided for AngularJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular).

In short, you'll need to:

- Configure your project to use TypeScript (i.e. setting up a `tsconfig.json`)
- Install the AngularJS type definitions (i.e. `npm i --save-dev @types/angular`)
- Write your AngularJS code in a style that leverages the type definitions ([Todd Motto's guide provides some good guidance about this](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide/tree/master/typescript))

Here's a very short example of such a style:

```
// Service.ts
export default class Service {
    constructor() {}
    log(message: string) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}

// Controller.ts
import ng from 'angular';
import Service from './Service';

export default class Controller implements ng.IController {
    static $inject: string[] = ['Service'];
    constructor(private service: Service) {}
    $onInit() {
        this.service.log('Hello, world!');
    }
}

// App.ts
import angular from 'angular';
import Controller from './Controller';
import Service from './Service';

export const angular
    .module('app', [])
    .service('Service', Service)
    .controller('Controller', Controller)
    .name;
```

If you give the above a try, you should be able to get IntelliSense happening for the `log` call inside `Service` from `Controller.ts`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering the question, do I understand this correctly, there is no way around refactoring my code to get this to work? I intended to move to TypeScript eventually but right now I'm trying to finish-up this round "as is" and the reason I need (wanted really) a more powerful IntelliSense was that the code base is getting huge (I know, AngularJS not really made for that...) so changing it now isn't really an option...

Comment: To be clear: I don't use TypeScript, but I did have bullet point #2 done. Adding a tsconfig.json file shouldn't be too hard but I'm wondering if there is a quick (and not too dirty) way to avoid doing bullet point #3?

Comment: Right, well, you could use `/// <reference types="..."` and manually author a `*.d.ts` (i.e. typings) file for the constructs in _each file_ you want IntelliSense for. However, I don't recommend this. It's duplicating the effort you'd otherwise get from authoring your source in a way that inference can be better provided. At the very least, this would still require your existing `*.js` files to be renamed to `*.ts` so that the triple-slash directive can apply.

Comment: OK I guess I'll hit the "abort mission" button on this one. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Being very late to the party: I have a legacy project in AngularJS (1.8.2) and lately decided to refactor the code a bit, for educational purpouse and personal challenge.

I've been able to make it work, somehow, even though I'm not certain it's the right/best way to do it, "it just works".

You must define your own service in a dedicated file (in my case decided to create a specific module):

**coreModule.js**

```
var coreServiceModule = angular.module('core', [<optional deps>]);
    class CoreClass {
        constructor(<optional deps>) {
            this.optional = optional;
        }
        method1 = function(){.....}
        method2 = function(){.....}
    }
    function CoreService(<optional deps>) {
        var instance;
        return {
            /**
            * @returns {CoreClass}
            */
            getInstance: function () {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new CoreClass(<optional deps>);
                    // so that it's not possible to call its constructor once instantiated
                    instance.constructor = null;
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
}
coreServiceModule.service('coreService', CoreService);
```

Then in your actual component file you have to inject the service and, **very important**, attach it to the component itself:
**myComponent.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
                'core' // the module defined above
    ]);
    myApp.controller('myAppController', ['coreService', function(coreService){

    // VERY VERY IMPORTANT FOR INTELLISENSE TO WORK
    let $ctrlMyApp = this;
    /**
    * @return {CoreClass} the return type
    * like this if you want to call it as a function (see below)
    */
    $ctrlMyApp.coreService = function(){
        return coreService.getInstance();
    }

    /**
    * @type {CoreClass}
    * this way if you want the instance/object itself
    */
    $ctrlMyApp.coreServiceInstance = (function(){
        return coreService.getInstance();
    })();

    // this way Intellisense will suggest methods defined inside CoreClass class of coreModule.js
    $ctrlMyApp.coreService().//here you'll find class methods suggestions
    $ctrlMyApp.coreServiceInstance.//here you'll find class methods suggestions as well
}]);
```

Better implementations are very welcome!
Hope it helps you as well, 6 years later, future programmer of legacy code <3